# Converting vector to orientation in sensor_msgs/Imu

Tags: ros, imu, ros-melodic, quaternion, lego

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the Lego Control+ Technic Hub as an IMU using [the node-poweredup library](https://github.com/nathankellenicki/node-poweredup). I am getting the imu data from the hub into ROS just fine but I am having trouble knowing how to correctly publish the orientation data in the sensor_msgs/imu message.

The data I'm getting from the hub is:

- Gyro: This is coming from the hub as [x, y, z] in degrees per second. I am converting this to radians per second and publishing it on the angular_velocity property of the imu message.
- Accel: This is the linear acceleration coming from the hub as [x, y, z] in milli-Gs. I am converting this to m/s^2 and publishing it on the linear_velocity property of the imu message.
- **Tilt**: This is coming from the hub as [x, y, z] where each value is in (-180, 180]. **This is the one I'm not sure how to use**. It seems like this is the orientation of the hub but the sensor_msgs/imu message expects a quaternion for the orientation.

**If I convert the 'tilt' vector to a quaternion via [this method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles) would that work? My understanding of quaternions isn't very strong, but I think it represents a rotation from another position. Is there some information not represented in that vector that would be necessary to accurately track the robot?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349831/converting-vector-to-orientation-in-sensor_msgs/imu/) by [JimmyTheFace](https://answers.ros.org/users/53707/jimmytheface/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like “tilt” is an orientation, which is what a quaternion represents (actually represents with fewer numerical instability to euler angles, which is sounds like what you have).

Converting to a quaternion will represent everything you need.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JimmyTheFace](https://answers.ros.org/users/53707/jimmytheface/) on 2020-04-18**:
Thanks. Yeah, that worked. I just used the algorithm on the wikipedia page to change it to a quaternion and it seems to be working fine.